# Are Chief Ministers in India entitled to different pension cycles even when their terms are repeating their tenure?

Tags: india, pensions, finance

Recently, the Chief Minister of Bihar, India, Mr Nitish Kumar changed the alliance partners and formed a [government with the support from a different political party](https://www.ndtv.com/india-news/nitish-kumar-tejashwi-yadav-stake-claim-in-bihar-to-form-jdu-rjd-government-3240040). He'll continue to remain as CM but as a formality, he resigned first and started a fresh tenure after taking a new Oath the next day. This is not the first case in India, there are many such instances.

But does this mean, that after the completion of every tenure he is entitled to a new lifetime pension even when they're terminating their own tenure and starting a new one?